# Left join with 3 tables does not work like I expect

Tags: mysql, left-join

I have these 3 tables:

- table for the roles
- table for the languages
- table for the translations of the roles

[image]

[image]

[image]

I would like to request all the roles with their translations, and if there is no translations then display 'to translate'.

I tried this without success:

```
select 
r.id_role, 
t.id_langue, 
case when t.id_langue is null then 'to translate' else t.libelle end
from role r 
left join trad_role t on r.id_role = t.id_role
left join langue l on t.id_langue = l.id_langue 
order by t.id_role;
```

In this example, the ADMIN role is not translated in English. So I expect to have 'to translate' for the English language. And I have not.

The result is:

[image]

I expect to have also this line:
ADMIN / en / to translate

What is the problem with my request?

I tried also like this, without success:

```
select * from
(select t.id_role, t.id_langue, t.libelle
from role r
join trad_role t on r.id_role = t.id_role) T1
left join langue l on l.id_langue = T1.id_langue;
```

Comment: Please do not put images of code in your question. It cannot be copied/pasted, making giving you an answer more difficult. I would have easily re-written your Select statement, but can't copy, and I'm not going to re-type the whole thing to make a couple of small changes.

Comment: Better hint, test for a column in langue instead of in trad_role in your case statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
select  
  r.id_role, 
  l.id_langue, 
  case when t.id_langue is null then 'to translate' else t.libelle_langue end
from role r
cross join langue l
left join trad_role t on r.id_role = t.id_role and t.id_langue = l.id_langue
;
```

Demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/30e71d/14

```
| id_role | id_langue | case when t.else               |
|---------|-----------|--------------------------------|
|   ADMIN |        fr |                 Administrateur |
|   ADMIN |        it |                  Administatore |
|   ADMIN |        en |                   to translate |
```

Comment: Thanks , it works fine now. I will study more in detail the "cross join" functionnality I did not know. Merci.

Answer (score 0):

You might give this a try:

```
select 
    r.id_role, 
    t.id_langue, 
    IF(l.id_langue is null,'to translate',t.libelle) as 'status'
from role r 
left join trad_role t 
    on r.id_role = t.id_role
left join langue l 
    on t.id_langue = l.id_langue 
order by t.id_role;
```

Basically, instead of testing a column from a table that is not left joined (and so won't be null), I'm testing a column from the left joined table.

Comment: thanks for the answer. I just tried : without success. I usually also make like you. But I really do not understand what happens. Sure that the pb is enormous and we do not see it !